# Escape the labyrinth

Tags: strategy, chess

Devise a concrete winning plan for White. The title will help. En passant is not possible.

[image]

FEN: 7k/8/6p1/3p1pPp/p1pPp1p1/PpPpPpPp/1P1B1P1B/3NRKQN w - - 0 1

Hint:

> You must find a way to liberate all your pieces. Shuffling pieces and the ability to comprehend the position are key.

Hint 2:

> Paul Lamford Puzzle 1981

Comment: Black or white to move? And what was the previous move? (White has possible en-passant captures if black's last move was f7f5 or h7h5.)

Comment: How come the bishops are both on a dark square?

Comment: It is not a legal position. There 12 black pawns too if you observe carefully. However it can be solved by creative techniques, it is a composed puzzle.

Comment: So I presume that a "creative technique" means an illegal move.

Comment: No, all normal chess rules apply here too. By creative, I mean it would require unusual and hard to find moves. There are tons of chess puzzles posted here that might be illegal in nature, but still requires you to move in valid ways. I was thinking of posting it in Chess SE but for some reason there is a lack of puzzles and it's oriented in a different direction.

Comment: Rot13(Juvgr pna znxr guerr zbirf. N) Ebbx pna zbir sbejneqf, gura vg vf gnxra ol bar bs gjb Oynpx cnjaf, juvpu znxrf Purpxzngr. O) Dhrra pna zbir sbejneqf, naq gur fnzr unccraf. p) Ovfubc q2-p1 ohg vg punatrf abguvat. Fb Juvgr zhfg unir fgnegrq sebz gur bgure fvqr, naq pna cebzbgr fbzr cnjaf ng gur obggbz.)

Comment: Which is what you just hinted, I think.

Comment: Rot13 (Gur cnja pnaabg tb onpxjneqf naq gb lbhe fhecevfr, Er2 vf gur pbeerpg zbir, naq svefg zbir lbh fubhyq znxr gb cebprrq va guvf cbfvgvba. Vg vf n abg n purpxzngr nf xr1 vf cbffvoyr. Gung'f jul V jnag crbcyr gb guvax bs perngvir jnlf gb rfpncr gur cnja oybpx, vg erdhverf zngrevny fnpevsvprf gb jva gur tnzr. Guvf vf jul V tnir vg gur anzr ynolevagu.)

Comment: Please do reveal the original inspiration [once the puzzle is solved](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/is-it-acceptable-to-post-a-puzzle-from-another-source-and-edit-in-attribution-on/5540#5540)

Comment: @I'mNobody Can you tell from where we can create this setup to analyse the moves?

Comment: @bobble Thanks for the insight. I have exactly followed what the answer says, I have used the core Idea and created a new puzzle. I will definitely post the source from where I found it.

Comment: @AbhinavLenka https://lichess.org/editor but do not post your solution or possible moves here in the comments please.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of position traditional engines struggle with, (huge material advantage but all of it locked away), so automatic solving is unlikely to be useful. My browser-Stockfish wants to take some offered white pieces, but that must be because the punishment is beyond its calculation horizon. When I manually stop those captures, it mostly just wiggles the white pieces back and forth.

Comment: I can smell out Otto Blathy anywhere!

Comment: @RewanDemontay That's a wrong guess :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the solution to the puzzle, but I won against a computer starting from this position (I'm playing white, computer is playing black). Maybe someone who is better than me at chess can explore all the different variations to this particular solution?

> 1.Bc1 Kg7
> 2.Re2 dxe2+
> 3.Ke1 Kh8
> 4.Kd2 Kg8
> 5.Qe1 Kf7
> 6.Qxe2 fxe2
> 7.Kxe2 Ke8
> 8.f3 Kf7
> 9.fxe4 fxe4
> 10.Ndf2 Ke6
> 11.Nxe4 dxe4
> 12.Nf2 Kf5
> 13.Nxe4 Kxe4
> 14.Bd2 Kd5
> 15.e4+ Kxe4
> 16.Be1 Kf5
> 17.Ke3 Kxg5
> 18.d5 Kf6
> 19.Ke4 Ke7
> 20.Ke5 Kd7
> 21.d6 g5
> 22.Kd5 h4
> 23.gxh4 g3
> 24.Bexg3 g4
> 25.Be1 g3
> 26.Bexg3 Ke8
> 27.Kc6 Kf7
> 28.d7 Kg6
> 29.d8=Q Kf5
> 30.Qe7 Kg6
> 31.Kd5 Kh6
> 32.Qg5+ Kh7
> 33.Ke6 Kh8
> 34.Kf7 Kh7
> 35.Qg7#

Comment: Black would never play dxe2, only the best defense. Playing against a computer and generating random moves lists (especially a weak one it seems, looking at your moves) isn't "solving" the problem at all.

Comment: @RewanDemontay I never really said that this was *objectively* the solution, I was merely posting this as an inspiration/stepping stone for others to continue off of what I did. Hence, why I said "Maybe someone who is better than me at chess can explore all the different variations to this particular solution?"

Comment: I appreciate that you thought of Qxe2, the only way to progress through, the computer is also extremely weak as it didn't even take the f3. Even though this solution lacks a lot of variation, have my upvote.

Comment: @I'mNobody I had the computer play against itself with this board setup, with white having much more playing power than black. Ignoring the fact that I used a computer, is that (using players of different strengths) cheating?

Comment: @DertereuuiFloireiurtrthr You are allowed to use computers the way you want. Computers struggle to solve such locked out positions so it may be futile to use a computer here.

Comment: @I'mNobody Actually, the computer solved it (well, the plan may not be concrete). I was really wondering whether I could post an answer that the computer, by itself, had figured out. If that's okay with you, I'll go ahead.

Comment: You can post the solution. I'll see if it is correct